# round to the nearest 1/16 and truncate to the nearest 1/16 of a value in C

Tags: c, math, truncate, rounding

Suppose size of a block is 1X1 and I have to move in steps of 1/16 along both the x and y direction. I want to round 0.53124 to the nearest 1/16 of the size of the block which is 0.5625. And similarly I want to truncate 0.53124 to the nearest 1/16 of the size of the block which is 0.5. Is there an efficient way of doing this? Please let me know.

Comment: What language are you using? This can be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Please use C. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way in most situations and languages would to be to

- multiply by 16
- round to the nearest integer
- divide by 16.

Comment: Even simpler, and often a better approach to this sort of problem, is to define a block to be 16x16 and do all work in 16ths.

Comment: And since 16 is a power of 2, accuracy won't suffer unless there's an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want *fixed point*, I would simply use fixed point (integers in units of 1/16) if possible. But if you really need to mix with floating point operations and round, one way is to *bias* all your values by a huge number such that the 1/16 place is the last place. Unfortunately with gcc, this approach can have problems on systems like i387 where floating point expressions are evaluated with extra precision, unless you're already using `long double` everywhere, so from a practical standpoint, Joachim's answer may be easier to make reliable (although it probably performs much worse).